# ayuda no me reconoce la url

Tags: php

aqui esta el codigo donde yo ingreso los datos para eso ya despues de haber entrado desde un login cacha el id del usuario que es el que logeo en este caso el unico que puede insertar es el administrador pero a la hora de querer insertar quiero que me regrese para el verUsuario para ver si se inserto pero sin que se modifique el id de la url y siga siendo el administrador pero me lo quita y asi no puedo ver ni su nombre de admin ni su area de trabajo

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>menu</title>
        <link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<Style type="text/css">
.costado{
border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-o-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
</style>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/images.png">
<script languaje="javascript">
function val(form)
{
        /////////////FALTA USUARIO/////////////
        if (form.Nombre.value == "")
        {
            alert("Falta Nombre ");
            form.Nombre.focus();return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //form.submit();
        }
        /////////////FALTA contraseña/////////////
        if (form.Apellidopa.value == "")
        {
            alert("Falta Apellido Paterno");
            form.Apellidopa.focus();return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //form.submit();
        }
        if (form.Apellidoma.value == "")
        {
            alert("Falta Apellido Materno");
            form.Apellidoma.focus();return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //form.submit();
        }if (form.Correo.value == "")
        {
            alert("Falta Correo");
            form.Correo.focus();return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //form.submit();
        }
        if (form.area.value == "")
        {
            alert("Falta Area");
            form.area.focus();return true;
        }
        if (form.usuario.value == "")
        {
            alert("Falta Usuario");
            form.usuario.focus();return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //form.submit();
        }
        if (form.contra.value == "")
        {
            alert("Falta Contraseña");
            form.contra.focus();return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //form.submit();
        }
        if (form.tipodeusuario.value == "")
        {
            alert("Falta Tipo de Usuario");
            form.tipodeusuario.focus();return true;
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Usuario agregado con exito");
            form.submit();
        }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<?
include "conexion.php";
$ID=$_GET["ID"];
//echo "$id";
//echo "$row[1]";
$query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE ID = '$ID' ";
$result = mysql_query ($query, $conexion);
$row = mysql_fetch_array ($result);

$query1 = "SELECT areas.encargado FROM areas,usuarios WHERE  usuarios.id = '$ID' && usuarios.area = areas.nombrearea ";
$result1 = mysql_query ($query1, $conexion);
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array ($result1);
?>
<h1 style="background-color:#CCFF00" align="center"> BIENVENIDO ADMINISTRADOR
  <p><? echo "$row[6]";?> area de <? echo "$row[5]";?> </p>
    <p>Encargado de Area <? echo JSON_DECODE($row1[encargado]);?> </p>
</h1>
        <br />
        <br /><br />
        <ul id="nav" >
            <li align="center" ><a href="#"><h2 align="center" >Equipos</h2></a>
             <ul>
            <li><? echo '<a href="equipos.php?ID='.$row[0].'">';?>Ver Equipos</a></li>
            <li><? echo '<a href="altaequipos.php?ID='.$row[0].'">';?>Agregar equipos</a></li>
            </ul></li>
            <li align="center" ><a href="#"><h2 align="center" >Usuarios</h2></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><? echo '<a href="usuarios.php?ID='.$row[0].'">';?>Ver Usuarios</a></li>
                    <li><? echo '<a href="altasusuarios.php?ID='.$row[0].'">';?>Agregar Usuarios</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li align="center" ><a href="#"><h2 align="center" >Fallos</h2></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><? echo '<a href="verfallos.php?ID='.$row[0].'">';?>Ver Fallos</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li><? echo '<a href="index.php">';?><h5 align="center" >CERRAR SESION</h5></a></li>
    </ul>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <div align="center">
 <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>

 <Form id="formalta" name="formalta" method="post" action="altusuarios.php?ID=$ID">
 <div align="center">
 <table width="308" border="1" bordercolor="#660099">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="font-size:24px" style="font-style:oblique"><div align="center">Altas de Usuarios</div></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="148">Nombre:</td>
    <td width="144">
      <label>
        <input type="text" name="Nombre" />
        </label>
 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Apellido Paterno:</td>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="text" name="Apellidopa" />
      </label>
    </td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Apellido Materno:</td>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="text" name="Apellidoma" />
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Correo:</td>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="text" name="Correo" />
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Area:</td>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="text" name="area" />
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Usuario:</td>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="text" name="usuario" />
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Contraseña:</td>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="text" name="contra" />
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tipo de Usuario:</td>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="text" name="tipodeusuario" />
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <label></label>
       <div align="center"><input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<? echo '$ID';?>"><input type="button" name="Submit" value="Guardar" onClick="val(this.form)"/></div>
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
</Form>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

este es el codigo donde se validan los datos para asi poder ingresarlos a la base de datos, el detalle esta en que cuando introduzco los valores y quiero que me regrese la url con el windows location no me reconoce el ID podrian ayudarme porque ingreso datos desde un usuario administrador y quiero regresar a la url con el id del usuario que los introdujo

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Documento sin t&iacute;tulo</title>
</head>
<body>
<?
    include "conexion.php";
    $ID=$_GET['ID'];
    $ClaveMaquina=$_POST['ClaveMaquina'];
    $Marca=$_POST['Marca'];
    $Mesa=$_POST['Mesa'];
    $fechaingreso=$_POST['fechaingreso'];
    $Procesador=$_POST['Procesador'];
    $SistemaOp1=$_POST['SistemaOp1'];
    $SistemaOp2=$_POST['SistemaOp2'];
    $CapacidadRam=$_POST['CapacidadRam'];
    $Estatus=$_POST['Estatus'];
    $usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
    $query1 = "INSERT INTO equipos(ClaveMaquina,Marca,Mesa,fechaingreso,Procesador,SistemaOp1,SistemaOp2,CapacidadRam,Estatus,usuario)
     VALUES ('$ClaveMaquina','$Marca','$Mesa','$fechaingreso','$Procesador','$SistemaOp1','$SistemaOp2','$CapacidadRam','$Estatus','$usuario')";
    $resultado = mysql_query($query1) or die ('Alta de registro fallida'. mysql_error());
    echo "<br><br><br><br><center><span class='Estilo3'>Se ha registado el Equipo correctamente"."<br>"."<br></center></span>";

    echo"<script languaje='javascript'> 
    window.location='equipos.php?ID=$ID'</script>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: La librería mysql es obsoleta y deberías cambiar a mysqli o, mejór aún, a PDO. Además, el incluir datos de formulario sin validación ni preparación hace que tu script sea vulnerable a ataques.

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes usar la funcion header para redireccionar asi

```
 $ID = $_GET['ID'];

header('Location:equipos.php?ID'.$ID);
```

Comment: hola la acabo de poner pero me sigue mandando lo mismo no me esta reconociendo el id

Comment: el id los recibes a travez de get desde la url ?

Comment: si tengo otra clase que es donde esta almacenado ese id cuando entro a logear pero a la hora de insertar no lo reconoce

Comment: muestra los otros archivos para poder ayudarte asi es complicado

Comment: listo ya lo agregue

Comment: lo que puedes hacer es guardar el id del administrador en una session y en tu otro archivo recoger ese id  session_start();  $_SESSION['ID']=22; es un ejemplo

Comment: ok ahorita lo pruebo gracias

Comment: Falta el signo igual: header('Location:equipos.php?ID='.$ID);

Comment: aun asi agregandole el signo no me quedo